# Unknown thick dashed border that obscures edited variable/function names in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

To replicate:

1. Install [ms-python.python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)
2. Open a valid Python file in VSCode

   - For testing, I am using the most starred `.py` gist: [min-char-rnn.py](https://gist.github.com/karpathy/d4dee566867f8291f086)
3. Delete a character from any variable

I then see this white dashed border-box when editing the variable `vocab_size`:

[image]

---

If I disable the ms-Python extension, the bordered box no longer appears

Is there a way to override the styling from ms-python (to make the border narrower or more transparent)?

Comment: try it with an other theme, it is some kind of syntax highlighting for `variable not found`, do you use a high contrast theme?

Comment: @KyleKing Is the same situation when you use other versions of python extensions? It is recommended that you disabled unnecessary extensions to avoid their mutual interference.

Comment: Thanks @rioV8 and @JillCheng, I had tried a few different non-HC dark themes; set `"window.autoDetectHighContrast": false`, and set the default HC theme to VS Dark+ (rather than the default HC theme), but still had the issue. I tried disabling all `python @installed` extensions and after reloading and activating ms-Python, I still saw the outline. I figured there might be some cached setting causing the problems, so I uninstalled `ms-Python`, quit VSCode, reinstalled, and reloaded the window. That appears to have fixed it!

Comment: Update: uninstalling didn't work. I didn't wait long enough to make sure it was fixed

So, I went back and tried a few light themes and the box appears as a thin black dashed border rather than white (although this is much thinner and doesn't obscure the variable name). I checked disabling a number of extensions and reloading the window to no avail. I also removed all settings in settings.json (set to just `{}`) and reloaded. I'm not sure what else to try?
As a note, the box only appears for global/local variables and disappears when the cursor is moved away from the variable name

Comment: @KyleKing Have you tried to re-enter this line of code manually? Or you can create a new file and paste the code into it.

Comment: Yeah, I copied pasted the text into a new file and this happens when writing a new line (and going back to edit it). I tried creating a new folder and project and saw the white border box issue as well

Comment: @KyleKing -It seems that this issue is a bit complicated and we need some time to study it. We will update it as soon as there is progress.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll keep thinking of things to try and add any updates. This also happens on both MacOS and Win 10

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! Turns out it was from a different package (see answer) that likely depended on ms-Python being enabled. I started from scratch disabling all extensions, then slowly enabled extensions in batches over the day. I resolved another bug and uninstalled a few packages, so overall a useful exercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dashed border-box is from the VSCode extension [hediet-power-tools](https://github.com/hediet/vscode-hediet-power-tools). There were two open related issues:

- https://github.com/hediet/vscode-hediet-power-tools/issues/5
- https://github.com/hediet/vscode-hediet-power-tools/issues/7

In `settings.json`, you can add the below setting to toggle between the available options: `dashed` (default) and `colored` where the latter works better on dark themes

```json
{
    "hediet-power-tools.applyRename.theme": "colored"
}
```